# How to lay a view above all of every tabbar view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have 2 questions:

The 1st one is:
I want to put a view that contain many buttons above the tab bar view. Even if I switch to whatever tab, I want to see that view. How is it possible?

The 2nd:
Can I handle the event when i click to the button inside that view? How to get that?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom parent view controller. Make the tab bar controller its child. Now you custom parent view controller can contain two views: the many-buttons view, and the tab bar controller's view.

The nice thing about this solution is that it can be configured with no code at all, entirely in the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Neat solution! Thanks.

Comment: I like this solution as well. Just remember that you will have to manually account for that second bar in your autolayout constraints and scroll view content insets to prevent the second bar from overlapping content.

Comment: If you're looking for how to "make the tab bar controller its child": add a "Container View", delete the small ViewController provided by default, and link the container view to your own tab bar view controller with an "embed" segue.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a UIWindow and set it's windowLevel to UIWindowLevelAlert. Then call it's makeKeyAndVisible to show it. Add your button in it.

Comment: I was going to suggest this at first, too, but on second thought, if the app ever shows any content without the tab bar, that might cause problems (e.g. "second bar" will still be visible if a modal is presented)